# How to keep bottom Navigation bar for every pages (inner pages)?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, flutter-test

In my Bottom navigation I have added 5 page 1st-pms, 2nd- SA, 3rd- Home, 4th- product, 5Th- profile,
In first tab pms page added text and button, when clicked on btn then redirect on inner pms page.

This is my Bottom navigation bar code.

```
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/Constants/constants.dart';
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/TabPage/SA.dart';
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/TabPage/pms.dart';
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/TabPage/producr.dart';
import 'package:bonanza_flutter/TabPage/profile.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'home.dart';

class BottomNav extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _BottomNavState createState() => _BottomNavState();
}

class _BottomNavState extends State<BottomNav> {
  final PageStorageBucket bucket = PageStorageBucket();
  final GlobalKey<ScaffoldState> _scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  var selectedATab ;
  Widget? currentAScreen;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState
    super.initState();
     selectedATab = 2;
    currentAScreen = Home();
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      endDrawerEnableOpenDragGesture: false,
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      key: _scaffoldKey,
      body: Stack(
        children: [
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
            child: Container(
              height: 100,
              width: double.infinity,
              color: Colors.green,
            ),
          ),
          PageStorage(
            child: currentAScreen!,
            bucket: bucket,
          ),
        ],
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        color: Colors.white,
        shape: CircularNotchedRectangle(),
        notchMargin: 8,
        child: Container(
          height: 60,
          width: 60,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 0),
          child: Row(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  // margin:selectedTab == 0 ? EdgeInsets.all(5): EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: selectedATab == 0 ? lightBlue : Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentAScreen = PMS();
                        selectedATab = 0;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset(
                          "assets/pms_icon.png",
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          color: selectedATab == 0 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'PMS',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: selectedATab == 0 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                                fontSize: tSize11),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  // margin:selectedTab == 1 ? EdgeInsets.all(5): EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: selectedATab == 1 ? lightBlue : Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentAScreen = SA();
                        selectedATab = 1;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset(
                          "assets/sa_icon.png",
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          color: selectedATab == 1 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'SA',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: selectedATab == 1 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                                fontSize: tSize11),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  // margin:selectedTab == 2 ? EdgeInsets.all(5): EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: selectedATab == 2 ? lightBlue : Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentAScreen =
                            Home(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                        selectedATab = 2;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset(
                          "assets/home_icon.png",
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          color: selectedATab == 2 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Home',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: selectedATab == 2 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                                fontSize: tSize11),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: selectedATab == 3 ? lightBlue : Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentAScreen = Product();
                        selectedATab = 3;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset(
                          "assets/product_icon.png",
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          color: selectedATab == 3 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Products',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: selectedATab == 3 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                                fontSize: tSize11),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                child: Container(
                  height: 60,
                  // margin:selectedTab == 4 ? EdgeInsets.all(5): EdgeInsets.all(0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                    color: selectedATab == 4 ? lightBlue : Colors.white,
                  ),
                  child: MaterialButton(
                    minWidth: 40,
                    onPressed: () {
                      setState(() {
                        currentAScreen =
                            Profile(); // if user taps on this dashboard tab will be active
                        selectedATab = 4;
                      });
                    },
                    child: Column(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Image.asset(
                          "assets/profile_icon.png",
                          height: 25,
                          width: 25,
                          color: selectedATab == 4 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                        ),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 3.0),
                          child: Text(
                            'Profile',
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: selectedATab == 4 ? skyBlue : greyColor,
                                fontSize: tSize11),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

This is my main page with bottomNav
[image]

### here when i clicked on click btn then it rediect on pms inner page,
now when  i am on pms inner page here also i want bottom navigation bar.

Comment: well i have a way, but it a bit hard to explain. i have a full code would you mind to read it?. only read a few part might give you how to do it using that

Comment: you need to make 2 page inside 1 file and use it to change between pages. but still in the sam screen

Comment: @Royalindo ok i want to read that because second idea will not work because I have more inner pages.

Comment: @Royalindo If you dont mind then share with me

Comment: check this https://justpaste.it/2kw9i  and read the bottom button

Answer (score 0):

One easy way to create a bottom navigation bar is the following:

```
Scaffold( body: Column(
          children: [
            Expanded(
              child: IndexedStack(
                  index: theIndexOfThePage,
                  children: [
                    // All the views with navigation bar

                    ViewNumber1(), 
                    ViewNumber2(),
                  ],
                )
            ),
            YourNavigationBar(), //
          ],
        ),
)
```